# Create a drupal page with a data table

Tags: drupal

What I want to do:

1. Setup data schema and import .csv data into drupal
2. create a drupal page that shows the data in the table

Is there any existing module can complete similar task?

PS: I am using drupal 7.x version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First create a content type as per your schema.

Then use the Feeds module (http://drupal.org/project/feeds) to import the data from the CSV.

Use Views (http://drupal.org/project/views) to create data-table.